# How to sort a vector of strings by char in Rust?

Tags: string, sorting, rust, vector

What is the more idiomatic way to sort a vector of strings by char?
Example:

Input:
`["3r", "2n", "2s", "7r", "1s", "1s", "6r", "1s", "1n", "1n", "5n", "9n", "3r"]`
Desired output:
`["1n", "1n", "2n", "5n", "9n, "3r", "3r", "6r", "7r", "1s", "1s", "1s", "2s"]`

First they need to be sorted on the second char so they are grouped together, after that sorted by first char.

I tried a bunch of things with `.filter` and `.sort_by` but was not successful.

Comment: What, specifically, have you tried? If your strings are all two characters long and you always want to sort by the second character first, you can just compare them in reverse.

Comment: I think you'd porbably be better off using a custom type instead of strings, and then implementing `Ord` for that custom type. That will probably make the rest of the processing more natural to implement as well.

Comment: @sven Interesting I looked into enum discriminant, that might be the better way indeed, but I need to research it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings are always two characters long, and you always want to sort them by the second character first, you can use `.sort_by` with a comparator which looks at the strings in reverse:

```rust
let mut input = vec!("3r", "2n", "2s", "7r", "1s", "1s", "6r", "1s", "1n", "1n", "5n", "9n", "3r");
input.sort_by(|a, b| a.chars().rev().cmp(b.chars().rev()));
let expected = vec!("1n", "1n", "2n", "5n", "9n", "3r", "3r", "6r", "7r", "1s", "1s", "1s", "2s");
assert!(input == expected);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can access chars in a string trough an iterator:

```rust
#[test]
fn sort_by_second_char() {
    let mut input = [
        "3r", "2n", "2s", "7r", "1s", "1s", "6r", "1s", "1n", "1n", "5n", "9n", "3r",
    ];
    let output = [
        "1n", "1n", "2n", "5n", "9n", "3r", "3r", "6r", "7r", "1s", "1s", "1s", "2s",
    ];

    // this does not break even if the input string is of invalid format, if
    // you are sure they are valid you can unwrap.
    fn get_second_char(s: &&str) -> (Option<char>, Option<char>) {
        let mut chars = s.chars();
        let [num, char] = [chars.next(), chars.next()];
        (char, num)
    }

    input.sort_by_key(get_second_char);

    assert_eq!(input, output);
}
```

Note that tuples implement `Ord` if their respective elements implement `Ord` Option implements `Ord` if type it wraps implements `Ord` (`char`)